# Proving Order of complexity proofs if f(n) is Ω(n∗g(n)), then f(n) is not O(g(n))

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Show that if f(n) is Ω(n∗g(n)), then f(n) is not O(g(n))

Assume f(n) is Ω(n ∗ g(n)) and f(n) is O(g(n)). Need to show a contradiction. The approach is to find a value of n that violates the definitions.
Proof: f(n) is Ω(n ∗ g(n)) implies there exists positive values C and k such that n > k implies f(n) ≥ C ∗ n ∗ g(n). f(n) is O(g(n)) implies there exists positive values C′ and k′ such that n > k′ implies f(n) ≤ C ∗ g(n).

So what value of n violates the definition and how can I show a contradiction?

Comment: There is no specific value of n that violates the conditions.  For any n, and any positive values of f(n) and g(n), you can make functions that take those values and are still within the asymptotic bounds.  Your proof has to show that f(n)/g(n) must grow larger than any constant bound as n increases.

Comment: @MattTimmermans The conditions are violated for `n > C'/C`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to prove the statement by contradiction is possible. But first of all, you need to be a bit more precise:

1. *f* and *g* are positive non-decreasing functions on integers
2. *C* and *C'* are >= 0
3. Your last implication should read `C' * g(n)` (as opposed to `C * g(n)`).

So we start with:

(a) There exist positive integers `C`, `C'`, `k`, `k'` such that for all `n > k` and `n' > k'`:

```
C * n * g(n) <= f(n) and f(n') <= C' g(n')
```

By chaining together your two implications and merging the two universal quantifiers into one (by noting that `for all n > k and n' > k'` implies `for all n > max(k,k')`), you immediately get:

(b) There exist positive integers `C`, `C'`, `k`, `k'` such that for all `n > max(k,k')`:

```
C * n * g(n) <= C' g(n)
```

Dividing by `g(n)` on both sides, which is valid by assumption 1. above, yields the equivalent:

(c) There exist positive integers `C`, `C'`, `k`, `k'` such that for all `n > max(k,k')`:

```
C * n <= C'
```

This is equivalent to:

(d) There exist positive integers `C`, `C'`, `k`, `k'` such that for all `n > max(k,k')`:

```
n <= C'/C
```

The last statement is equivalent to false. This is a contradiction and hence the original statement is true.

Comment: The asymptotic definitions say "there exists positive values C...".  If the asymptotic conditions are not met for particular choices for `C` and `C'`at some abscissa `n`, then you're free to choose different ones.  And, in fact, for any given `n`, there will always be choices for `C` and `C'` for which the conditions are satisfied.  This proof does not work.

Comment: @MattTimmermans The proof is correct. Maybe you got the order of the quantifiers wrong. I originally omitted the quantifiers because I thought it was obvious but I made them explicit now for clarity. If you still have doubts please state the exact step (a, b, c or d) that you are doubting.